# Spliting training data into multiple variables using R

Tags: r, bigdata

So right now I am trying to create multiple variables with training data, and in the process I have reached an error

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '1.band1' not found

which is a product of these lines:

`for(i in 1:length(data_split)){
 assign(paste("fit.lda",i, sep = ""), train(class~., data=data_split[i], 
 method="lda", metric=metric, trControl=control))}`

is it something that I did wrong or is it something that can be fixed with another methodology

EDIT: 
My dataset is a data frame which was created by the following lines

`validation_index <- createDataPartition(valuetable$class, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
dataset <- valuetable[validation_index,]`

where `valuetable` is a dataframe which containes the values of multiple rasters.

Now, I wanted to split my data so my train function can be processed faster, that is because my machine's specs are pretty low, thus allowing me to re-create the later the results that would take time using other methods.

*Let me know if you want more clarification*.

Comment: What is `data_split`? Is it a `list` containing the data subsets?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explained how is your dataset and its variables, so I'll put a generic example.

Let's say your dataset has a variable called `SET`, whose content is `TRN` for training and `TST` for test. To create a dataset containing only training set you have to use the following code:

`trn.ds<- ds[ds$SET == 'TRN',]`

If you need a test dataset, just adapt the code:

`tst.ds<- ds[ds$SET == 'TST']`

PS: It wasn't me who downvoted your question, I don't understand why people downvote almost every question here.

Comment: I understand the confusion, most of the time users need more clarification. Now I added more information to my problem if you have any idea on how to solve my problem feel free to input your opinion or solution